# Jenkins Publish Over SSH Plugin filename variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, build.gradle

I have a Jenkins job that invoke a `gradle` script to create a *.war* file from sources.

`gradle war` command produces a file with name `Geo-1.0.5.war` because `build.gradle` use version number:

```
war {
    baseName = 'Geo'
    version = '1.0.5'
}
```

This file will be copied and deployed on a Wildfly server trough SSH using "Publish Over SSH Plugin".

How can I tell to the plugin that the war filename format is something like Geo-*$gradle_version*.war?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is documented if you click the `(?)` help icon next to the "Source files" field within Jenkins:

> The string is a comma separated list of includes for an Ant fileset eg. `**/*.jar`
>   (see [Patterns](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) in the Ant manual).

So in your case, you could use `**/Geo-*.war` as the source pattern.

This is also shown in the screenshot on the [plugin wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin#PublishOverSSHPlugin-ConfigureajobtoPublishOverSSH), and in the [Source Files](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over#PublishOver-Sourcefiles) and [Examples](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over#PublishOver-examples) sections on the linked "Publish Over…" documentation.

---

In your comment to this answer, you mention that you don't want to communicate that the filename is "something like Geo-$gradle_version.war" for uploading, but rather want to use the exact filename in a script being executed on the SSH host.

You could do this by adding an Execute Shell step which determines the filename, and exporting it as an environment variable using the [EnvInject Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject).  For example:

```
f=$(basename `find . -name 'Geo-*.war'`)
echo WAR_FILENAME=${f} > env.properties
```

Then, by using an Inject Environment Variables step with its path set to `env.properties`, the `WAR_FILENAME` value will be added to the build environment, available for use by subsequent steps.

In the Exec Command field of the SSH-publishing step, you can then use `${WAR_FILENAME}` to refer to the exact filename uploaded.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Wildcards can be a workaround but i was searching a way to pass the exact war name to the script executed after SSH copy.

Comment: You should have clearly mentioned that in your question then. I've added to my answer.

Comment: @ChristopherOrr what if the **Source files** path is in another workspace, how can I specify that? Documentation says that it is relative to the job's workspace but my artifact is produced by a different job. I have an open question for that - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49615692/publish-over-ssh-plugin-cant-copy-build-archive