# Publish over ssh plugin - can't copy build archive

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I have been struggling for hours with this thing and I have spent time reading some of the suggested similar questions but couldn't find a hint or solution.

I have a build job that creates a build archive. Then I have a separate deploy job that should take that archive and copy it over ssh to a remote environment. I am using the [publish over ssh](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) Jenkins plugin. Everything seems to go well except for the copy part. No files are copied to the remote location.

I get the following:

```
Started by user admin
Building in workspace /usr/lib/jenkins/workspace/preprod-deploy
SSH: Connecting from host [xxxxxx]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [xxxxxx] ...
SSH: Creating session: username [xxxxxx], hostname [xxxxxx], port [22]
SSH: Connecting session ...
SSH: Connected
SSH: Opening SFTP channel ...
SSH: SFTP channel open
SSH: Connecting SFTP channel ...
SSH: Connected
SSH: cd [/var/www/test_automation]
SSH: OK
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [xxxxxx] ...
SSH: Transferred 0 file(s)
Build step 'Send files or execute commands over SSH' changed build result to SUCCESS
Finished: SUCCESS
```

My guess is that there is something about the way I'm trying to configure the **Source Files** path (*The base directory for this fileset is the workspace* as per the tooltip).

My build archive is located in  **/usr/lib/jenkins/job/build/${BUILD_TO_DEPLOY}/artifact/*zip*/archive.zip** where BUILD_TO_DEPLOY in a natural number corresponding to the build job.

According to the console output, the workspace of the deploy job is **/usr/lib/jenkins/workspace/preprod-deploy**

This is my configuration:
*Ignore the exec command - that is just for testing purposes - but it works - it is successfully creating the txt file to the remote directory*

[image]

Any ideas how can I overcome this?

Comment: The ${BUILD_NUMBER} variable is build number of the deploy job. I think you want build number of the build job here.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out, unfortunately it was't the cause. I have updated the image and text.

Comment: maybe you can try with relative path like `../../job/build/${BUILD_TO_DEPLOY}/artifact/*zip*/archive.zip`.

Comment: it looks like there is a *Copy Artifact Plugin* that can be added in the build step and can be used to copy the artifact from the build job workspace to the deploy job workspace

Comment: Yes you would need to copy the artifact in the deploy job workspace. Source Files reads files only from the current directory as mentioned [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns)